# Different results between Expended and Factored calculation

Tags: java, math

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double value = 1.25 * ((19.6 / 100) + 1);
        System.out.println(value);
        Double value2 = (1.25 * (19.6 / 100)) + (1 * 1.25);
        System.out.println(value2);
    }
}
```

which result is :

```
1.4949999999999999
1.495
```

and I don't understand why these are different...

I added explicitly parenthesis to test different cases, and I don't understand why the `Factored` form return `1.49499` and the `developed` form return what i want : `1.495`.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not precise. It doesn't completely follow the real number arithmetic rules.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 2):

If you need precise results with floating points you can use BigDecimal class.

```
BigDecimal factor = new BigDecimal(19.6);
BigDecimal multiplier =  new BigDecimal(1.25);
BigDecimal oneHundred = new BigDecimal(100);
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);

BigDecimal res = multiplier.multiply(factor.divide(oneHundred).add(one));
System.out.println(res);

BigDecimal res2 = multiplier.multiply(factor.divide(oneHundred)).add(one.multiply(multiplier));
System.out.println(res2);
```

results in:

```
1.495000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
1.495000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal(String)` constructor.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: could you explain why? Is there any difference between BigDecimal(1) and BigDecimal("1")?

Answer (score 1):

Because certain floating point numbers cannot be represented by a finite number of bits without rounding .   [Floating-point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) have a limited number of digits, they cannot represent all [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) accurately: when there are more digits than the format allows, the leftover ones are omitted - the number is rounded.

You should probably read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/101197/46777).

> i don't understand why the factored form return 1.49499 and the developped form return what i want : 1.495.

I am not sure of the exact reason , but it seems in the first case the intermittent results itself were rounded.

Answer (score 1):

**BASIC CONCEPT**
1. when we do `addition` of two `decimal` number it never `extends` its decimal point.
2. when we do `multiplication` of two `decimal` number it will `extends` its decimal point as require.

**To understand concept Java Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double v1 = (19.6/100);
        System.out.println("inti v1 = "+v1);
        v1 += 1; 
        System.out.println("1 + v1 = "+v1);
        v1 *= 1.25;
        System.out.println("Ans = 1.25 * v1 = "+v1);
        Double v2 = (19.6 / 100);
        Double v3 = (double) 1;
        System.out.println(" inti v2 = "+v2);
        System.out.println("inti v3 = "+v3);
        v2 *= 1.25;
        v3 *= 1.25;
        System.out.println("1.25 * v2 = "+v2);
        System.out.println("1.25 * v3 = "+v3);
        Double v4 = v2+v3;
        System.out.println("Ans v2 + v3 = v4 = "+v4);
    }}
```

**OutPut**

```
 1. inti v1 = 0.196
 2. 1 + v1 = 1.196
 3. Ans = 1.25 * v1 = 1.4949999999999999

 4. inti v2 = 0.196
 5. inti v3 = 1.0
 6. 1.25 * v2 = 0.245
 7. 1.25 * v3 = 1.25
 8. Ans v2 + v3 = v4 = 1.495
```

Indicated line number in output to get easy understand concept.

**This is not different program but one by one process which follow in maths for `+`/`*`,in your code.**

You can see in output,
`Line 3`,`Line 6`,`Line 7` there we do multiplication there it `extended` its decimal point.
and in `Line 2` & `Line 8` we do `addition`, as you know `addition` never extend its decimal point get largest decimal point to display.